# Prove if number is rational or irrational

Tags: irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

I've been asked to prove if $\frac{\sqrt{3+\sqrt5}}{\sqrt{2} + \sqrt {10}}$ is a rational number. I've tried a proof as follows: 
Suppose the number is rational, so it can be written as the quotient of 2 numbers $a$ and $b$
\begin{align*}
   \frac{\sqrt{3+\sqrt{5}}}{\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{10}} = \frac{a}{b} \\
   \frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{12 + 4\sqrt{5}} = \frac{a^2}{b^2} \\ 
   \frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{4(3+\sqrt{5})} = \frac{a^2}{b^2} \\
   \frac{1}{4} = \frac{a^2}{b^2}
\end{align*}
And because we get $\frac{1}{4}$ which is rational, we can conclude that the proof is right and there aren't any contradictions. Hence $\frac{\sqrt{3+\sqrt{5}}}{\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{5}}$ is a rational number.

I guess my proof lacks something and I don't feel it's complete yet. I would appreciate any recommendations on how to improve my answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would take a look at $(\sqrt2+\sqrt5)^2$ again.

Comment: Note that $\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2$ is rational, but $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ is not. You'd need to tweak your logic there.

Comment: How did you get $(\sqrt2+\sqrt5)^2$ to be $12+4\sqrt 5$? I get $7+2\sqrt{10}$.

Comment: It helps to know that $(1+\sqrt5)^2=6+2\sqrt5$.

Comment: Yes! You're all right. Sorry for my silly mistake. I wrote the incorrect number.  I've corrected the number.

Comment: @Beats2019 That is certainly an improvement, though as I was saying before, you shouldn't conclude that the number is rational just because its square is. The fact that the square is $\frac{1}{4}$, and the number is clearly positive, implies that the result is $\frac{1}{2}$, which is certainly rational. Barry Cipra's hint can also be used here to get the same result, by simplifying $\sqrt{3 + \sqrt{5}}$.

Comment: Now I get it better. Thank you all for your kind answers and advice.

Comment: @Beats2019 Your line of proof is fine, but there is no reason to carry $\frac{a}{b}$ throughout. Just replace it with $x$, then the last line will show that $\frac{1}{4}=x^2$ so $x=\frac{1}{2}$ since it is known to be positive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\frac{\sqrt{3+\sqrt5}}{\sqrt{2} + \sqrt {10}} =\frac{\sqrt{6+2\sqrt5}}{\sqrt{2}(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt {10})} = \frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2+2\sqrt{5}}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: how does one see (or come up with) that 1+sqrt(5)=sqrt(6+2sqrt(5)).

Comment: @lalala we have $6+2\sqrt{5} = 5+2\sqrt{5}+1=(\sqrt{5}+1)^2$

Answer (score 3):

Consider
$$
x=\dfrac{\sqrt{3+\sqrt{5}}}{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{10}}
$$
Then you know that $x>0$. Then
$$
x^2(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{10})^2=3+\sqrt{5}
$$
that becomes
$$
x^2(2+10+2\sqrt{20})=3+\sqrt{5}
$$
and therefore, owing to $2\sqrt{20}=4\sqrt{5}$,
$$
4x^2=1
$$
so $x=1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach:

In a problem like this, my first step is to clear the denominator.

$\displaystyle \frac{\sqrt{3 + \sqrt{5}}}{\sqrt{10} + \sqrt{2}} \times \frac{\sqrt{10} - \sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{10} - \sqrt{2}} = \frac{1}{8} \times \left[\sqrt{3 + \sqrt{5}}\right] \times \left[\sqrt{10} - \sqrt{2}~\right].$

Therefore, the problem reduces to an examination of

$$ \left[\sqrt{3 + \sqrt{5}}\right] \times \left[\sqrt{10} - \sqrt{2}~\right].\tag1$$

Since both of the factors in (1) above are positive, the problem reduces to determining whether there exists positive rational numbers $a,b$ such that $a^2 \times b^2$ equals the square of the expression in (1) above.

This resolves to determining whether there exists positive integers $c,d,e,f$ such that

$$\frac{c^2 e^2}{d^2 f^2} = \left[3 + \sqrt{5}\right] \times \left[12 - 2 \sqrt{20}\right].$$

$$\left[3 + \sqrt{5}\right] \times \left[12 - 2 \sqrt{20}\right] = \left[3 + \sqrt{5}\right] \times \left[12 - 4 \sqrt{5}\right] = 16.$$

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{\sqrt{3+\sqrt{5}}}{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{10}}\!=\!\dfrac{\sqrt{\left(\sqrt{\dfrac12}+\sqrt{\dfrac52}\right)^2}}{2\left(\sqrt{\dfrac12}+\sqrt{\dfrac52}\right)}\!=\!\dfrac{\sqrt{\dfrac12}+\sqrt{\dfrac52}}{2\left(\sqrt{\dfrac12}+\sqrt{\dfrac52}\right)}\!=\!\dfrac12.$